# python extract value from nested list

Tags: python, list

The function is working fine for **single level** and for **nested dict path in the list** but not for **nested list elements**. I have added the example data, sample code and current output. The output seems fine except the first one which returns empty.

```
data = [
    {
        "rate_id": 174596,
        "rate_code": "ACE",
        "room_types": [
            {
                "id": 1450,
                "name": "Queenn",
            },
            {
                "id": 1451,
                "name": "King",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "rate_id": 174340,
        "rate_code": "DFD",
        "cancel_rule_info": {"a":5},
        "room_types": [
            {
                "id": 1452,
                "name": "Suite",

            }
        ]
    }
]

from typing import List, Any

def extract_values_nested(data: List[dict], key_path: str) -> List[Any]:
    """
    Extracts values based on a nested key path from a list of dictionaries.

    Args:
        data (List[dict]): A list of dictionaries.
        key_path (str): The nested key path to search for its corresponding values.

    Returns:
        List[Any]: A list of values corresponding to the specified nested key path.
    """
    keys = key_path.split('.')
    results = []

    def extract_recursive(subdata, keys):
        if isinstance(subdata, list):
            for item in subdata:
                extract_recursive(item, keys)
        elif isinstance(subdata, dict):
            key = keys[0]
            if key.isdigit():
                key = int(key)
            if key in subdata:
                if len(keys) == 1:
                    results.append(subdata[key])
                else:
                    extract_recursive(subdata[key], keys[1:])

    for entry in data:
        extract_recursive(entry, keys)

    return results
```

## Test cases

```
print(extract_values_nested(data, "room_types.0.id"))
print(extract_values_nested(data, "room_types"))
print(extract_values_nested(data, "rate_code"))
print(extract_values_nested(data, "cancel_rule_info.a"))
```

**Output**

```
[]
[[{'id': 1450, 'name': 'Queenn'}, {'id': 1451, 'name': 'King'}], [{'id': 1452, 'name': 'Suite'}]]
['ACE', 'DFD']
[{'a': 5}, {'d': 5}]
```

Comment: Note that the first dict in the sample list is missing the key `cancel_rule_info`, and even though the second dict has the key `cancel_rule_info`, the key path `"cancel_rule_info.a"` should return `5` rather than `{'a': 5}` or `{'d': 5}` as incorrectly shown in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test this :

```py
from typing import List, Any

def extract_values_nested(data: List[dict], key_path: str) -> List[Any]:
    """
    Extracts values based on a nested key path from a list of dictionaries.

    Args:
        data (List[dict]): A list of dictionaries.
        key_path (str): The nested key path to search for its corresponding values.

    Returns:
        List[Any]: A list of values corresponding to the specified nested key path.
    """
    keys = key_path.split('.')
    results = []

    def extract_recursive(subdata, keys):
        if not keys:  # exit condition
            return

        key = keys[0]

        # If the key is a digit and the data is a list, try accessing the list using the key as an index
        if key.isdigit() and isinstance(subdata, list):
            idx = int(key)
            if idx < len(subdata):
                if len(keys) == 1:
                    results.append(subdata[idx])
                else:
                    extract_recursive(subdata[idx], keys[1:])
        elif isinstance(subdata, dict) and key in subdata:
            if len(keys) == 1:
                results.append(subdata[key])
            else:
                extract_recursive(subdata[key], keys[1:])

    for entry in data:
        extract_recursive(entry, keys)

    return results

data = [
    {
        "rate_id": 174596,
        "rate_code": "ACE",
        "room_types": [
            {
                "id": 1450,
                "name": "Queenn",
            },
            {
                "id": 1451,
                "name": "King",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "rate_id": 174340,
        "rate_code": "DFD",
        "cancel_rule_info": {"a":5},
        "room_types": [
            {
                "id": 1452,
                "name": "Suite",

            }
        ]
    }
]

print(extract_values_nested(data, "room_types.0.id"))
print(extract_values_nested(data, "room_types"))
print(extract_values_nested(data, "rate_code"))
print(extract_values_nested(data, "cancel_rule_info.a"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the dotted key path goes only in one direction without backtracking there is no need for any recursion. A simple iterative item getter loop will do:

```
def extract_values_nested(data: List[dict], key_path: str) -> List[Any]:
    results = []
    keys = key_path.split('.')
    for entry in data:
        for key in keys:
            if isinstance(entry, list):
                key = int(key)
            entry = entry[key]
        results.append(entry)
    return results
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNNa4NAEIbv/orBS7JgJWmSfggphKa9tJfSYxBZdG2W6rrsjqUS8tvTUZM0HySk1IO6@8y8M/O66grnhRrcabNapabIASst1QfIXBcG4VVa9GCiKsdJRAriGw2PMfriWSlspIRFkXQTjjxoQmeJjDH04FNUkeY4D8CiYXD10FLSCQMH6DLClhlaGMMsbDYoo15tEn2rM4ndjt9hDU4LA0KhqUAqaOo12xtEaTWoRX5BfckUpJXKIlex6DYKHmTUC9uPW7dAHUiFXXpje7gtPW6fM8LhFq8n8bnWQiVtCbaeEUujNgEOOUh91xM3dLFVcA1HEcnEDaB/Oxzd33gHKC4SQdCdPD65u6wo8og@l7AEZ3v9Lo6Gc1v94ajnHTPF86bAWymEUu5@xNK7VLp/RvqFDtWh8HbVurkudMqYwbB3ypjp83TXmLj@2FlkyoyyVVpQyMLldB8t/23f9ZkZ30uJgho5P6UTOo429TE7/Td5u@35PZ@qM/a3rEsTtj4ytlr9AA)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work and can be easily expanded to include e.g. attribute access. It can also easily be made recursive:

```
from operator import itemgetter

access_functions = (
    lambda b: itemgetter(b),
    lambda b: itemgetter(int(b)),
)

def access(obj, keypath, default=None):
    bits = keypath.split(".")
    for bit in bits:
        for func in access_functions:
            try:
                obj = func(bit)(obj)
                break
            except (TypeError, KeyError, IndexError, ValueError):
                pass
        else:
             return default
    return obj

d = {"foo": ["bar", {"baz": 5}]}
access(d, "foo.1.baz")
# 5
```

Comment: I don't want to access to the value, I already have a method for that to safely deep access but I want to iterate `List[dict]` and from it, I want the results as `List[Any]`